# Django syncdb fails with circular reference in abstract models

Tags: python, django

I found an interesting behavior in djangos syncdb mechanism, as I tried to sync my database for a new deployment last time.

I got two apps `alphabet` and `core` where core stores most of my models.
Now I created a new **abstract** model in alphabet with a code like:

```
class Compare(models.Model):
    percentage = FloatField(default=0)
    speakers = IntegerField(default=Speaker.objects.count())

    class Meta:
         abstract = True
```

and the referring model in the core app:

```
class Speaker(models.Model):
    language = CharField(max_length=300)
```

When I try to sync the database with the syncdb command it fails with `ProgrammingError` because the table core.speaker does not exist.

Why is syncdb even checking abstract models? How can I solve this circular reference in my project?

(I am using Django 1.6 by the way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `count()` in the field definition is incorrect. Django tries to evaluate the query when the model is loaded. In your case, this is before the table has even been created. Even if the table had been created, the query would only be evaluated once each time the module loads, and would not update as instances were created and deleted.

You can pass a callable to a model field as the default, so you could try

```
speakers = IntegerField(default=Speaker.objects.count)
```

Then the query will be evaluated when the model instance is created.

Comment: perfect! Thank you so much.